# BlackBerry Simulator & BIS Push Service

Tags: java, blackberry, push, blackberry-push

I am hoping that someone knows if you can use RIMM's push service with BIS WITHOUT a hand held device. I have registered for the push evaluation and I want to program a push server that will send out notifications to BB clients. I got my email this morning containing:

```
Server:
Application:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Pwd: xxxXXXXX
CPID (Content Provider ID):xxx
Start Date (MM/DD/YYYY): X/X/XXXX
Expiry Date (MM/DD/YYYY):X/X/XXXX
First Name:XXXXXXX
Last Name:XXXXX
Email:xxxx@xxxx.com
Account Type:Plus
Source IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Usage:BIS
```

AND

```
Client:
Application Credentials (for use in your client application):

Application ID:XXX-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Push Port:xxxxx
```

I am hoping someone can tell me where to get started - as an iPhone developer, I have to say, there is much more information.

Lastly, if I DO need a device, does that device have to have a dataplan? I wanted to be able to serve my clients from WiFi as well, does the BB push system work only on Cell networks?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Push server needs a PIN number, and that all simulator got the same PIN , you need a real device and an Dataplan to test it.

They can't reach a Simulator because you are not on any known Carrier.

Comment: again, thanks for these great answers Michael. If you can pass on a particular resource that you use, I would also appreciate that. I have a long history as a Java programmer, but there are subtle difference that are enough be annoying

Comment: @Submerged All the documentation is Here http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers but I also got a contact Directly at RIM, so I can get the kind of information I gave you on this question.